# Grunt wiredep to inject bower components issues

Tags: gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

I'm using the grunt task wiredep to inject all of my bower components into my index.html and having some issues. I'm trying to start very basic like so -

```
wiredep: {
      target: {
        src: 'index.html'
        }
    },
```

in index I just have

```
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- endbower -->

  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- endbower -->
```

Everything else is injected properly however when I run the task I'm getting this error.

```
  Running "wiredep:target" (wiredep) task
   Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/project/bower.json' Use --force to continue.
```

Having trouble debugging this - could use any help!

I also have my .bowerrc pointing to the right directory (I think)

```
{
     "directory": "bower_components"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you create the `bower.json` file on `project/` directory?
if you haven't, run

```
$ bower init
```

and fill the answers. When it asks you to

```
set currently installed components as dependencies?`
```

answer yes. the new `bower.json` file is now generated and will be populated according to your existing bower packages.